# Google map not showing map pointer image on the exact point

Tags: javascript, html

This map is working fine but the problem is that the map is not showing the map pointer as the map is being displayed for easy location. how can i add google map point on the map for easy tracking of the location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            html, body, #map_canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initialize() {




            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.4076658, 39.08393430000001),

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
            }




            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the page on the google developers website talks all about it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
}
```

use this in your map along with the script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```